# What is difference of between pulse-triggered FF(Flip Flop) and edge-triggered FF

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

What is difference of between pulse-triggered FF(Flip Flop) and edge-triggered FF.

Let me know please.

Comment: pulse triggered?  do you mean level triggered?

Comment: um... when I ask my instructor he said level triggered and pulse triggered are equal term. But I confuse because   I  thought Latch(== level triggered), Flip Flop(== edge triggered). Sorry for my broken english. I'm not used to this language

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to know how they are different by function? Or how they are different by structure (i.e. how they are made)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the people use Latch and FF are used interchangeably (as a generic term also). I have read and heard two definitions of latch and flip-flops (FF).

- Some differentiate them on the clock triggering (FF:edge-triggered, Latch:level-triggered).
- Some differentiate based on the presence of clocking signal (FF:clocked, Latch:not-clocked).

(See [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29) they have mentioned both the points. )

---

All have an agreement on two points:

1. Latches are level-triggered, they can never be edge-triggered
2. FFS are always clocked

So what do we call something that is 'clocked' and 'level triggered'? People call these either as *clocked Latch* or *level triggered FF* based on the definition they follow.

In other words, level-triggered/pulse-triggered and clocked latch mean the same thing  - they are sensitive to the 'level' of  clock not to the transition.